# How do I solve this Javascript variable reference mess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

So, here is the problem I am having:

```
app.controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope, TestData) ->
  $scope.name = 'World'
  TestData.get(0).then (data)->
    $scope.elem = data  
  TestData.get(1).then (data)->
    $scope.elem2 = data

  $scope.callFunc = ->
    TestData.modify1()
    TestData.modify2()

app.factory 'TestData', ($q,$timeout)->

  data = [{
    name: "TestData #1"
    id: 1
  },{
    name: "TestData #2"
    id: 2
  }]


  funcs = {}

  funcs.get = (id)->
    deferred = $q.defer()
    $timeout(->
      deferred.resolve(data[id])  
    ,500)
    return deferred.promise

  funcs.modify1 = ->
    data[0].name = "DataTest #1"

  funcs.modify2 = ->
    data[1] = {
      name: "DataTest #2"
      id
    }

  return funcs
```

I don't know how I get around this, but I want to update an element in an array. I understand that replacing it will not work. But how do I get around that?

If it were just name/id it would not be a problem. But the actual models have a lot of different data to it and I don't want to update them all individually.

Here is a plnkr showcasing the problem (in case it helps): http://plnkr.co/edit/cBXJsIghlIeIUQGLfZfe?p=info

(I do understand the theory behind why it does not work, I'm mostly looking for the most efficient way to solve this problem.)

Comment: What about using angular.extend to overwrite the properties in your old object?  http://plnkr.co/edit/SZa4KUMp7MtG3FxNaoVY

Answer (score 1):

To copy all the properties of object `in` into object `out`, you can do:

```
for k of in
  out[k] = in[k]
```

I am not sure exactly what you are doing (not too familiar with Angular), but you might get some ideas here: http://plnkr.co/edit/LKb6NQ4u0dORLya42LED

```
$scope.callFunc = ->
  TestData.modify $scope.elem, 0
  TestData.modifyAlt $scope.elem2, 1

...


funcs.modify = (incoming,i)->
  console.log "incoming:",incoming
  for k of incoming
    data[i][k] = incoming[k]

funcs.modifyAlt = (outgoing,i)->
  console.log "data[i]:",data[i]
  for k of data[i]
    outgoing[k] = data[i][k]
```

Comment: The data comes from my Server API. If it changes on the server I tell the client to reload it, which it then does, it however disconnects the references. I am trying to avoid this as it makes it overly complicated in my implementation.